# Examples for ideals that can not be finitely generated

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, integers, principal-ideal-domains

In $\mathbb{Z}$ [every ideal can be generated by $1$ element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)#Example), so $\mathbb {Z}$  is a [principal ideal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain).

I'm looking for specific examples (rings) for which

- every ideal can be generated by at most $2$ elements
- every ideal can be generated by at most $3$ elements
- ...
- every ideal can be generated by a finite set of elements
- there are ideals that cannot be generated by a finite set of elements

Does this question/search make sense at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rings for which every ideal is generated by a set of $n$ elements or less are said to have the **n-generator property**. I'm not too sure about the specifics of examples for each particular $n$. There is probably a family of examples out there somewhere.

[Dedekind domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain) are prominent examples of rings with the $2$-generator property. In fact, they are informally said to have the property that their ideals are "$1\frac12$-generated."  I can't remember exactly the reason for this: I thought I remembered it had to do with being able to choose one of the elements. [1](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250130558)

The commutative rings for which the ideals are all finitely generated are exactly the [Noetherian rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_ring).

In light of the last answer, we can say that a (commutative) ring has a non-finintely generated ideal iff it is not Noetherian, so any non-Noetherian ring will do.

What I've said for the last two questions holds equally well for noncommutative rings, but I've just been keeping everything in the straightforward context of commutative rings with identity.

Comment: I could not find the **n-generator property** at DaRT. Would you mind to link to it?

Comment: @HansStricker Most of the [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22N-generator+property%22&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS793US793&oq=%22N-generator+property%22&aqs=chrome..69i64.4995j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) results are relevant, although some are for other structures.

Comment: Why is the question for an example for a non-Noetherian ring not useful?

Comment: @HansStricker OK, I reread it, and for the purposes of building a list of examples, it is useful.  Sorry about that.  I've rephrased. Examples and descriptions of rings of the types I mentioned abound, so I don't think I'll parrot them here again.

Comment: Which previous question? How can a question asking for a specific example be equivalent to some other questions asking for other examples?

Comment: @HansStricker  Because you are asking *about the complement of the class you just asked about*. A PID is already an example of everything except the last property, for which any nonNoetherian ring will do, say $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb R$.  If you desire an $n$-generator ring that is not $n-1$-generator ring, then I'm afraid I can't help in the general case.

Comment: I didn't ask about the class, but about an example for the class.

Comment: @HansStricker That's one of the [main features](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/commsearch/) of my site... I thought you knew(?) . You can find Dedekind domains that aren't PIDs, Noetherian rings that aren't Dedekind domains, and nonNoetherian rings with ease there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84196/discussion-between-hans-stricker-and-rschwieb).